# Как можно сделать экспорт html таблицы в excel по шаблону

Tags: javascript, excel

Нужно вытащить html таблицу в excel или ворд,через js, но чтоб можно было сделать определенный шаблон. Пробовал библиотеку jsexcel но она выводит тупо таблицу, а вопросом по шаблону там и не пахнет. Посоветуйте что нибудь)

Comment: эта библа вытягивает элемент ДОМа? есть варик просто написать и использовать  функцию-шаблонизатор перед тем, как отправить в библу таблицу?

Comment: Которую библиотеку использовал, она просто вытаскивала таблицу в excel. Любые альтернативы подойдут, в которых можно шаблон изменить под себя. То ли я плохо ищу, то ли такого нету

Comment: варианты есть разные:
1) https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-tables
2) https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

Comment: но имхо, вам придется писать функцию-шаблонизатор, под ваши нужды. вопрос только в том, как вы ее реализуете

Comment: А если через php сделать экспорт таблицы из бд, а через js сортировку по чекбоксу? Думаю этот вариант проще реализовать

Comment: вы можете забрать таблицу из бд, отдать ее в js, в js представить ее в виде массива объектов (объект = элемент/ линия таблицы), где вы сможете свободно редактировать данные, менять их местами и тд (функция-шаблонизатор), а затем преобразовать этот массив обратно в таблицу и с помощью jsexcel вытащить ее из ДОМа.

Comment: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table - здесь можно ознакомиться с современным представлением таблиц в памяти приложения

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, сделал без js.

Comment: напиши плз своё решение в ответы для потомков

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
$db_host = "localhost"; 
require_once 'PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$phpexcel = new PHPExcel();
$page = $phpexcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
$page->setCellValue("A4", "Дата");
  $page->setCellValue("B4", "Марка и завод. № оргтехники");
  $page->setCellValue("C4", "Инвентарный №");   
  $page->setCellValue("D4", "Наименование выполненных работ по замене деталей, использованию материалов");
  $page->setCellValue("E4", "Кол-во");
  $page->setCellValue("F4", "Цена,руб");
  $page->setCellValue("G4", "Сумма,руб");
  $page->setCellValue("H4", "Отдел");
  $page->setCellValue("I4", "ФИО ответственного лица");
  $page->setCellValue("J4", "Подпись ответственного лица");
  $page->getRowDimension('4')->setRowHeight(39);
  $page->getColumnDimension("A")->setWidth(10);
  $page->getColumnDimension("B")->setWidth(10);
  $page->getColumnDimension("C")->setWidth(12);
  $page->getColumnDimension("D")->setWidth(22);
  $page->getColumnDimension("E")->setWidth(4);
  $page->getColumnDimension("F")->setWidth(8);
  $page->getColumnDimension("G")->setWidth(8);
  $page->getColumnDimension("H")->setWidth(8);
  $page->getColumnDimension("I")->setWidth(12);
  $page->getColumnDimension("J")->setWidth(12);
  $page->getRowDimension("1")->setRowHeight(23);
  $page->getRowDimension("2")->setRowHeight(25);
  $page->getRowDimension("3")->setRowHeight(27);
  $page->getStyle("A1:K1")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("A2:K2")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("A3:K3")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
$borderr = array(
  'borders'=>array(
    'outline' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
      'color' => array('rgb' => '000000')

    ),
  )
);
$page->getStyle("A4:J4")->applyFromArray($borderr);
$border = array(

  'borders'=>array(

    'inside' => array(

      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,

      'color' => array('rgb' => '000000')

    ),
  )
);
$page->getStyle("A4:J4")->applyFromArray($border);


  $styleTable = array(

  'font' => array(

    'name'      => 'Times New Roman',

    'bold'      => 'true',

    'size'      => 10,              

  )
);
  $page->getStyle('A4:J4')->applyFromArray($styleTable);
  $style = array(

  'font' => array(

    'name'      => 'Times New Roman',

    'size'      => 12,              

  )
);
  $page->getStyle('A1:J1')->applyFromArray($style);
  $page->getStyle('A2:J2')->applyFromArray($style);
  $page->getStyle('A3:J3')->applyFromArray($style);

  $page->getStyle("A4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("A4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("B4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("C4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("D4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("E4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("F4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("G4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("H4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("I4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("J4")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

  $page->getStyle("A4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("B4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("C4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("D4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("E4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("F4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("G4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("H4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("I4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("J4")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  $page->getStyle("A4:J4")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

  $s = 4;




$db_user = "web"; // Логин БД
$db_password = "adminbifk"; // Пароль БД
$db_base = 'printers'; // Имя БД
$db_table = "Applications"; // Имя Таблицы БД
$mysqli = @(new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base));
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');
foreach ($_POST['xport'] as  $value) {
  # code...

$query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT *  FROM Applications WHERE id=" .$value);


  
 
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
  
  {
  $s++;

    
    $page->getStyle("A:J")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $page->getStyle("A:J")->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
    $page->getStyle("A:J")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $page->getStyle('A:J')->applyFromArray($style);
    $page->getStyle("A$s:J$s")->applyFromArray($borderr);
    $page->getStyle("A$s:J$s")->applyFromArray($border);
    $page->setCellValue("A$s", $row['date']);
    $page->setCellValue("B$s", $row['printer_model']);
    $page->setCellValue("C$s", $row['number']);   
    $page->setCellValue("D$s", $row['service']);  
    $page->setCellValue("E$s", $row['kol']);   
    $page->setCellValue("F$s", $row['price']);  
    $page->setCellValue("G$s", $row['sum']);  
    $page->setCellValue("H$s", $row['office']);  
    $page->setCellValue("I$s", $row['surname']);  
    $page->setCellValue("J$s", "");
  } 
    
    }
    
    $page->setTitle("Example"); 
    $page->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    $page->getPageMargins()->setTop(1);
    $page->getPageMargins()->setRight(0.3);
    $page->getPageMargins()->setLeft(0.3);
    $page->getPageMargins()->setBottom(1);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpexcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save("example.xlsx");
     header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xlsx');
    exit(readfile('example.xlsx'));
?>
```